# How can I use all function arguments inside javascript Object.assign method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a server using `nodejs` & express in which user can request some data and server send response. But, the data is array and I want to send a json response to the user. So, I used `forEach()` method of array and use `Object.assign()`, so that I can get object. But the problem is I cannot use 'index' argument of `forEach()` method while 'value' argument is properly getting used inside the callback function. When I use only 'index' argument, then my code runs ok but I want to use both arguments at the same time.

```
route.get('/getGPX/:number', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    gpx.find({ username: req.user.username }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        if (result) {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                res.end();
                console.log('ended')
            }
            else {
                var jsonRes = {};
                result.forEach((value, index) => {
```

I can use 'value' but not 'index' from the arguments

```
                    jsonRes = Object.assign({ index: value.data }, jsonRes);
                })

                res.json({data: jsonRes});

            }
        }
    })
```

I even tried using `global var`, but even it's not working, how can I use index as well as value argument at the same time

Comment: It's really unclear what `result` looks like and what you want the `jsonRes` to become. Can you please post example data? Also, try to achieve your aim first with normal loops and assignments, not `forEach` and `assign`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the JSON structure that you want ?

if you want a json like :

```
{
  0: "my first value",
  1: "second"
}
```

You just miss `[]` around index, here you put 'index' as a key not the value of index. So you override the index key in each iteration.

Here is the code that use the value of index as a key in a json.

```
jsonRes = Object.assign({[index]: value.data}, jsonRes)
```

See here for a working example with more examples : https://repl.it/@Benoit_Vasseur/nodejs-playground

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` mutates the left-most parameter. it does not produce a new object. Since you are passing a literal object every time the jsonRes is going to be the last result.

Put jsonRes in the left instead - `Object.assign(jsonRes, {index: value.data})`

Comment: For this use case, you would however write just `jsonRes.index = value.data;`

Comment: @Bergi lots of ways this code could be written, was just trying to demystify what they were currently seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a simple `reduce` instead of `forEach` and `Object.assign`:

```
} else {
  var jsonRes = result.reduce((r, v, i) => {r[i] = v.data; return r}, {});
  res.json({data: jsonRes});
}
```